# Travelling to Schengen area with Type-D national Visa of Spain

Tags: schengen, europe, france, spain, multiple-entry

Can I travel to France with my 90-days Type-D Visa (Trabajo Y Residencia) of Spain ? Its a Multiple Entry Visa. I had applied for Residence card (T.I.E) but did not receive yet. My Visa is valid till Sept, 2015.

I know this question has been asked multiple times but there is no final conclusion anywhere and the person who had asked the question never confirmed wether he/she was able to travel. Its good if they update the post with their experience.

I would like to confirm few things:

1. On my VISA, its not mentioned "Schengen" anywhere. It says valid for "ESPANOL". So its a national visa of Spain. Is it sufficient ?
2. Few people are suggesting to get a 'autorizacion de regreso', which is a return permit. But I have multiple entry visa, so do I need to get 'autorizacion de regreso' ?

Answer (score 2):

Refer to this: http://europa.eu/rapid/press-release_MEMO-10-111_en.htm

> **Third-country nationals holding a long-stay visa issued by a Member
>   State are allowed to move freely in the territory of Member States
>   under the same conditions as the holder of a residence permit.**
>
> The Visa Code will abolish the "D+C" visa (i.e. a long stay visa
>   allowing the holder to circulate in the territory of Member States the
>   first 3 months of his stay on the basis of the national long stay
>   visa).
>
> Because of the abolishment of the D+C visa a new Regulation amending
>   the Convention Implementing the Schengen Agreement and Regulation (EC)
>   No 562/2006 as regards movement of persons with a long-stay visa has
>   been drawn up and is to apply at the same date as the Visa Code.
>
> **The Regulation will allow third-country nationals holding a long-stay
>   "D" visa issued by a Member State to move freely in the territory of
>   Member States for 90 days in any 180-day period, under the same
>   conditions as the holder of a residence permit**.
>
> This will put an end to the difficulties third-country nationals had
>   to face when legally staying in a Member State on the basis of a D
>   visa and would restore the basic philosophy underlying the area
>   without internal borders, i.e. that a person can travel within that
>   area for short stays with the document on the basis of which he or she
>   is legally present in a Member State.

Comment: "That a person can travel within that area for short stays with the **document** on the basis of which he or she is legally present in a Member State". So what would be that **document** ?

Comment: @Geeky It would be either a type D visa or a residence permit.  (A type D visa may also be called a *long-stay visa* or a *national visa.*)